# Using awk to interpolate data based on if statement

Tags: bash, awk, interpolation

so I am trying to automate a data collection process by using awk to search the file for a certain pattern and plug values into the linear interpolation formula. The data in question tracks time versus position, and I need to interpolate the time at which position equals zero. Example:

```
100  0.5
200  0.2
300  -0.3
400  -0.7
```

Then, my interpolation looks like this:

interpolated_time = 200 + (0 - 0.2) * (300 - 200) / (-0.3 - 0.2)

I am going to write the script in bash and use bc calculator for the arithmetic. However, I am inexperienced with using awk and cannot figure out how to correctly search the file.

I want to do something like

```
awk '{if ($2 > 0) #add another statement to test if $2 < 0 on next line#}'
# If test is successful, store entries in variables or an array
```

The interpolation may need to be performed multiple times in one file. I may need to output all values in question to an array, and then input the paired indexes into the interpolation formula. (i.e. indices [1,2] [3,4] [5,6] are paired together for separate interpolations)

I know that awk works on a line-by-line test loop, but I don't know if there is a way to incorporate the previous or next line in the test (perhaps something like

```
next
```

or

```
getline
```

?)

Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the result `240`

```
awk '{if(p2>0 && $2<0) print p1-p2*($1-p1)/($2-p2); p1=$1; p2=$2}'
```

doesn't handle if 0 is already in the data set and assumes transition is from positive to negative.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to tweak it a little bit to fit my needs but this was very helpful!